# IE ActiveX plugin cannot create file

Tags: mfc, activex

I wrote an IE plugin using MFC activex. The plugin actually creates a file in CLSID_APPDATA folder and writes some data inside it. But the problem is that file which is created cannot be seen (i mean i cant see any file in CLSID_APPDATA folder on windows vista) whereas I am actually writing data inside it. The plugin is not signed. 
I have the code from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/161873 to mark my activex component as safe. 
Please let me know if I need to do something more to make it possible for file creation. I hope I was clear. Do let me know if I need to provide more details.

regards,
Pradip.B

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It sounds like you're falling foul of IE's "Protected Mode" which redirects file writes made from IE from \Users\UserName\Local\ to \Users\Username\LocalLow (or something very similar to that).

Take a look at the following links as they should point you in the right direction:

- [More details on Protected Mode IE in Windows Vista](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2005/09/20/471975.aspx)
- [The difference between Local and LocalLow folders](http://www.vistapcguy.net/?p=173)